# Make a specific/custom route - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am trying to make a route for my app at `/details` to show all categories. (I am using index for something else), but I am getting `Uninitialized constant Category Controller`:

`routes.rb`

```
get '/details' => 'category#category_details', as: 'details'
```

`category_controller.rb`

```
def category_details
    @categories = Category.all
end
```

`category_details.html.slim`

```
.row.results-heading
  .col-sm-4
    h3.blue Vehicle Details
  .col-md-4.col-sm-6
    h3.blue Select Your Vehicle Category
    .tax-details
      span.i-icon i
      | &nbsp;&nbsp;
      span.additional Additional surcharges, local taxes, etc. may apply
  .col-sm-2
    span.i-icon i
```

If I run rake routes I get:

```
details GET    /details(.:format)       category#category_details
```

Comment: and what class is defined in your `category_controller.rb` ?

Comment: `class CategoriesController < ApplicationController`

Comment: why downvote and not say why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined your route as pointing to `category#category_details`, which translates to "the `category_details` action in the `CategoryController` controller".

Your controllers name is `CategoriesController`, so the route should be changed to be `categories#category_details`.

**NOTE**: Your filenames should also always match your class names. It is incorrect in Rails to have a class called `CategoriesController` in a file called `category_controller.rb` - it should be `categories_controller.rb`.

Comment: That was exactly it, duh....Thank you. I will give best answer when I am able to in 7 minutes.

Comment: Also, it is called categories_controller.rb in my project, I just screwed that up in SO